# SqlException: can I get the database name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have an exception logging service, used by a variety of systems. It is given an exception, which it extracts useful information from, and stores.

If the exception is a [SqlException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx), then it extracts extra details like the 'Server' property (that's the SQL Server instance) and the stored procedure name and line, to assist with diagnosis.

But I can't find the 'database name' anywhere in there, which would help to clarify exactly where the error occurred. Can anyone tell me where it is?

I'm aware that SQL is not specific to SQL Server; but `SqlException` is specific to SQL Server, so it should be there somewhere..

P.S. changing every piece of SQL somehow to throw differently is not an option. And neither is changing the C# code where the exception is coming from. All I've got to work with is the `SqlException` object in memory.

Comment: *I'm aware that SQLClient is not specific to MS-SQL*, well, it is...

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for clarifying that...which gives me even more hope that it *should* be there. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: You are talking about the default SQLException.. Other option to find the database name is to Customize your error exception according to your working current DB connection.(Code behind)

Comment: Sorry, @reds, I made it clear in the question that changing the C# code where the exception is coming from is not an option.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the "Server" gives you the SQL server instance (as I mentioned in my question), not the database name.

Comment: If you storing connectionstring in web.config or in properties than you can apply logic to get catalog name from there

Comment: Sorry, @Saurabh; but I thought the question made it clear that I am working on an error handling service which handles exceptions from a variety of systems (the implication being that it doesn't know anything about any of the systems that the exception came from). So I'll say it again...I only have the SqlException to work with.

Comment: I had a SqlException yesterday while debugging my code and the database name was not stored anywhere in the exception. Unfortunately it seems to me someone has asked you to make an apple pie and but given you oranges. 
Alternatively do you have any logging on the database server that could be queried by the error handling service. Can the database be deduced from what has raised the error or does the error service not know where the error has came from.

Comment: @Scrobi. SqlException is specific to Sql Server (for example, it gives the SQL server instance, and I can get the stored procedure name), so there *should* be a database in there somewhere. To use your analogy I'd say that someone has asked me to make apple pie from an apple. To answer your question "can I deduce?" no, check the comment above yours.

Comment: I hope you find what your looking for but I would raise a possible concern that your error handling services does not know where the error was raised. If you manage to find the database name in the exception it may not indicate and issue with the database but an application, e.g. not passing in a parameter to a stored procedure. You will then need to track down the failing application. 
If you do find a way round this issue add your answer for others.

Comment: @Scrobi The name of the application where it occurred is given to the exception logging service in addition to the SqlException, so it's easy to know which application it occurred in.  The example you give about a missing SP parameter is good... even if you know the code where the exception came from, and you decide that the code is correct, if that code might be using one of several databases with the same SP, how do you know which of those databases the SP is missing the parameter?

Comment: My concern is alleviated, though I still don't a see away you can achieve this without refactoring how the errors are communicated to the error handling service.

Answer (score 0):

The default [SQLException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) has no property for the database name

It does have a collection of [SQLErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror(v=vs.110).aspx) which, I presume is where you are getting the stored procedure etc.. from. This does contain more information about the error but again does not store the database name.

You could look at customising your error exception:

e.g.

```
public class MySqlException : DbException
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
} 

SqlConnection conn;
try
{

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw new MySqlException() {Database = conn.Database};
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @Scrobi, I made it clear in the question that changing the C# code where the exception is coming from is not an option.

Comment: sorry missed the P.S at the end of your question.